# Fetch current date and filename from Penatho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am new to pentaho BI and been with pentaho for quite few days.
But I couldn't fetch the current time from pentaho. May I know if any of you could help me.
And i would also like to know how to fetch the filename of the file that is passed as input

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can use get system info step and select the option to select current time based on the suitable format you want, on second question, you can use get a file name step to get filename from the string.